# JPA TableGenerator behaviour in clustered environment

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using `TableGenerator` for my project, below is the snippet for the same.

```
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator =    " TableGenerator")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "TableGenerator", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator", parameters = {
  @Parameter(name = "table_name", value = "TABLE_GENERATOR")}
```

I know that `hibernate` will cache min value and max value in the memory  for a given entity and update min and max value in `TABLE_GENERATOR` (Let's assume that value may be 50-100).

But I am not sure what will the be behaviour of JPA/Hibernate `TableGenerator` in a clustered environment, i.e. there will be multiple JVMs so what will be cached min/max value for same in each of JMV and what value will be updated in Table:TABLE_GENERATOR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally have not used TableGenerator in a clustered environment, believe it should work but because you're hitting a single table there's always the possibility of concurrency or transactional issues.

IMO table-generated keys are only relevant when you can't use sequence numbers - which most platforms support - and have plenty of advantages:

- guaranteed uniqueness
- operates outside any transaction, so no locking issues, no reuse of numbers caused by a rollback, whatever
- supports cache values, so each thread or cluster element can get a range to work with that are guaranteed to be unique, if you cache groups of 25, thread 1 gets 1-25, thread 2 gets 26-50, etc., etc.
- supported by hibernate

If sequences aren't an option, this might work but I not convinced there aren't holes to work around.